# Need help regarding object detection in Azure Custom Vision

Tags: object-detection, image-recognition, hololens, microsoft-custom-vision

I need to detect a chair, but only when it's in center

So, I captured a video such that the chair covers all parts of the image in every frame

I need to classify between two classes - chair is in center AND chair is not in center

So, I am not getting how to tag each image?

As seen in the below image, should the tag region cover the entire frame?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to think about the formulation of your problem. If you want to classify the entire image frame as to whether there is a chair in the center or not, you might want to cast it as an image classification problem rather than an object detection problem. Essentially you want to do a binary classification of the entire image as to whether there is a chair in the middle or not. So you would have a two class classification problem.

This would be simpler to train, because you would not have to supply bounding boxes, and result in a simpler and more portable model.

To build classification models easily in Watson Studio, you could check out https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/visual-recognition?topic=visual-recognition-tutorial-custom-classifier (programmatically) or https://dzone.com/articles/build-custom-visual-recognition-model-using-watson (with Watson Studio GUI)

If you would like to continue with object detection check out https://medium.com/@vincent.perrin/watson-visual-recognition-object-detection-in-action-in-5-minutes-8f97c4b613c3

Answer (score 0):

Once you know where the chair is using object detection, you can do simple math to tell whether it is in the center or not.